# Can I use Sass(css preprocessor) in Visual Studio Express 2013 for web?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, sass, visual-studio-express

if yes then how 
because

Mindscape Web Workbench and SassyStudio (free plug-in) Tool not support in vs express free version

and how to compile SCSS to css
i already done this

Install-Package SassAndCoffee

[image]

Comment: Sass has nothing to do with visual studio if you compile using CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got the solution

First add this via NuGet console

```
Install-Package SassAndCoffee
```

and in page.cshtml page

```
<link href="~/Content/SassDemo.css?@ViewBag.ID" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

viewbag.ID for no need to clear cache of browser every time

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ID = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            return View();
        }
```

now run and change variable values for colors u will see effect in css

SassDemo.scss

```
$color: red;

   .a{
           width: 100%;
    }

    .mainDiv {
        @extend .a; /*Extend/Inheritance  */
        /*width: 100%;*/
        border: 1px solid $color;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .childDiv {
        height: 55px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 130px;
        background-color: $color;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```